# $\hom_{\mathbb{Z}}(\mathbb{Q}, C) = 0$ for every cyclic group $C$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, homological-algebra

This is part of an exercise I'm doing, exercise 2.22 Rotman, Introduction to homological algebra.

Prove that $$\hom_{\mathbb{Z}}(\mathbb{Q}, C) = 0$$ for every cyclic group $C$.

Any hint ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$\mathbf{Q}$ is a divisible group.

Comment: This is good, but I wonder might there be another way intended since this is in a homological algebra book?

Comment: Who cares what that book is? It for sure assumes some basic group theory, and using that $\;\Bbb Q\;$ is a divisible group and thus *any* homomorphic image of it is also a divisible group, and finally that the only finite divisible group is the trivial one, wraps it all at once. Good hint. +1

Answer (score 1):

The book already shows that $\textrm {Hom}_{\mathbb Z}(\mathbb Q, \mathbb Z) = 0$, so assume that $C=\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$. Let $f: \mathbb Q\to C$ be a morphism and compute
\begin{align*}
f(a/b) = f(na/nb) = nf(a/nb) = 0
\end{align*}
for any rational $a/b$.